# Accent marks/symbols not displaying correctly in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, unicode, utf-8

Anytime there's an accent mark (é or ') or symbol (&) in my database it displays as HTML code. The table CHARACTER SET is UTF-8 Unicode and the COLLATION is utf8mb4_general_ci, which should display those characters correctly. Any ideas why this is happening?

(MySQL version 5.7)

**Current data**

```
`company`| `firstname`| `lastname`
----------------------------------
A&amp;T  | Patrick    | O&#039;Brien
```

**Expected**

```
`company`| `firstname`| `lastname`
----------------------------------
A&T      | Patrick    | O'Brien
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this is html encode use a function to convert it see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I'm currently using another function to capitalize these cell values. So my query would now look like `proper(HTML_UnEncode('company'))`,`proper(HTML_UnEncode('firstname'))`,`proper(HTML_UnEncode('lastname'))`, which nearly doubles the query time. Any tips?

Comment: Sorry i meant you update all rows '**once ** and change the code that inserts the html encoded text . if that is not prossible, do a before insert and update, which converts the the text before inserting

Comment: so with a BEFORE INSERT trigger?

Comment: when you have code that insert and updates your database produces this html encoded text of course both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106328/discussion-between-msklut-and-nbk).

Answer (score 1):

Fix the data source to store actual characters into MySQL, not "HTML entities".

Where necessary, use output routines such as PHP's `html_entities()` and/or `urlencode()`